# what are the differences between using "BETWEEN" operator and "<= and >= " (arithmetic) operators?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am learning oracle database specifically Oracle 11g. And came across a doubt that the same functionalities could be achieved when we are using "BETWEEN" operator and "<= AND >=" (Arithmetic Operators)" for ex:

SQL> select employee_id , first_name , salary from employees where salary between 10000 and 15000;

is giving the same output as

SQL> select employee_id , first_name , salary from employees where salary >=10000 and salary <=15000;

Could you guys please help me understand what are the differences here.

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/BETWEEN-Condition.html#GUID-868A7C9D-EDF9-44E7-91B5-C3F69E503CCB) shows that those two are equivalent. (Though what is evaluated, and how often, can be different, as it also says.)

Answer (score 1):

The following two conditions are identical:

```sql
WHERE salary BETWEEN 10000 AND 15000
WHERE salary >= 10000 AND salary <= 15000
```

Which version you use is up to you and a matter of taste.  The `BETWEEN` version is a bit more terse, so many would pick this version from the two options.

Comment: Thanks Tim for the help.